# How to use Mono<Boolean> in if else conditional statement?

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming

I am using `Flux<Document>` in reactive, so as to make my Rest Service reactive. I am returning `ResponseEntity<Flux<Document>>` as response to my rest service. Right now my service is always returning `HttpStatus.ok()`, but I want to enhance it to return `HttpStatus.noContent()` in case of no content is found.
To achieve this am trying to check the size of Flux. I figured out that this can be achieved either by `.count()` or `.hasElements()`.

IF I consider `.hasElements()` then it returns `Mono<Boolean>`.
I am trying to understand as a newbie that how can I use this in making decisions between `HttpStatus.ok()` and `HttpStatus.noContent()`.

Also is this the right way to use conditional statements in reactive or is there any other way to achieve it.

Request you to please help.

Comment: Please add your code to the question instead of describing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I did to accomplish the above ask:

```
final Flux<Document> returnDoc = <Reference of what I received from the Service layer>;

return returnDoc.hasElements()
                .map(isNotEmpty -> {
                    if (isNotEmpty) 
                        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(returnDoc);
                    else {
                        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
                    }
                });
```

This worked for me. Let me know if there is any other solution which is better.

Comment: I think you should make use of `filter()`, `mapNotNull()`, `switchIfEmpty()` operators here

Answer (score 0):

The trick with reactive conditionals is to utilize a couple of operators to achieve the `if / else` behaviour.

Some operators I learnt from using Webflux over the years:

- `filter()`: filters the stream by some predicate (e.g. `if (2 > 1)`)
- `map()`: maps the response to some type if `filter()` emits `true`
- `flatMap()`: maps the response to a `Publisher` (i.e. `Mono/Flux`)
- `switchIfEmpty()`: emits a default `Publisher` if `filter()` emits `false`
- `defaultIfEmpty()` emits a default type

I will share my redisson cache & r2dbc code as an example.

Here is our scenario in pseudocode:

```
If a key is found in cache
  return value
Else 
  call database
  set key & value pair in cache
  return value
```

In either case, the value is wrapped into a `ResponseEntity` distinguished by status and the body.

```java
@Override
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Res<UserSettings>>> getUserSetting(String username) {
  Mono<UserSettings> queryAndSet =
      userSettingsRepository
          .findByUsername(username)
          .flatMap(v1 -> cacheRepository.set("user_settings", username, v1).thenReturn(v1));

  return cacheRepository
      .get("user_settings", username, new TypeReference<UserSettings>() {}) // if then
      .switchIfEmpty(queryAndSet) // else
      .map(ResponseUtil::success) // if then
      .defaultIfEmpty(singleError(UserMsg.USER_SETTINGS_NOT_FOUND.getCode())) // else
      .map(v1 -> ResponseEntity.status(elseNotFound(v1)).body(v1)); // finally
}
```

`CacheRepository` interface specs:

```java
public interface CacheRepository {
  Mono<Void> set(String table, String key, Object value);

  Mono<Void> set(String table, String key, Object value, Long ttl, TimeUnit timeUnit);

  <T> Mono<T> get(String table, String key, TypeReference<T> type);

  Mono<Boolean> delete(String table, String key);
}
```

`ResponseUtil` that helps with `ResponseEntity` wrapper:

```java
public class ResponseUtil {
  private ResponseUtil() {}

  public static <T> Response<T> success(T data) {
    return Response.<T>builder().success(true).data(data).build();
  }

  public static <T> Response<T> singleError(String error) {
    return Response.<T>builder().success(false).errors(List.of(error)).build();
  }

  public static <T> Response<T> multipleErrors(List<String> errors) {
    return Response.<T>builder().success(false).errors(errors).build();
  }

  public static HttpStatus elseBadRequest(Response<?> res) {
    return Boolean.TRUE.equals(res.isSuccess()) ? HttpStatus.OK : HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
  }

  public static HttpStatus elseNotFound(Response<?> res) {
    return Boolean.TRUE.equals(res.isSuccess()) ? HttpStatus.OK : HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
  }
}
```

And the `Response`:

```java
// Idiotic wrapper
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Response<T> {
  private T data;
  private boolean success;
  private List<String> errors;
}
```